# Excel VBA Resize picture in a certain range

Tags: excel, vba, image, resize

Ok i have an image that a 3rd part software is placing into an excel file.  in order to get the resolution needed it has to be sized much larger than needed.  It will always be placed in the same location and be a specific size.  I need to resize it.  Ideally it would be automatic when the excel file opens but i think any vba code would end up acting before the information is inserted, but if there was a small delay that would be cool too.  Alternatively i could make do with a button that runs a bit of code.  The code below works, but only when the picture is specifically named "Picture 179" which it won't be ever again or at least until the counter recycles.

The image is inserted at Cell A45 specifically but it extends through roughly cell AZ60.

Here is what i've got that doesn't work.

```
Private Sub Resize_Graph_Click()
   ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 179")).Select
   Selection.ShapeRange.Height = 104.4
   Selection.ShapeRange.Width = 486.72
End Sub
```

Comment: Are there other shapes on the sheet? if no, you could loop through each shape

Comment: @BigBen just got back to this one... i missed that second part of the sentence =/  doesn't change that the with statement would suffice, though it looks like this can be marked as a duplicate, since it relates to looping through shapes.  will find the one coming to mind (includes `typename`, i believe)

Comment: @Cyril yeah I'm pretty sure there's a dupe somewhere.

Comment: Bryan, where is the "specific range" listed in your title?  It looks like you just want to loop through your shapes on the worksheet, adjusting `.height`/`.width`.  Neither your code snippit or "The image is inserted at Cell A45 specifically but it extends through roughly cell AZ60" explicitly state that you're actually searching for images only in A45, or from A45 to AZ60, etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize all images on a worksheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52503204/how-to-resize-all-images-on-a-worksheet).  Chose this as duplicate due to the lack of a "specific range" to look through shapes.

Comment: @Cyril I understood it to be just one image.

Comment: @BigBen true, but you have to A) find the shape and B) act upon it.  it looks like we don't know the name at whatever stage of the counter, so the for each, even if just having 1 shape, would be a quick-find.

Comment: We also don't know what other shapes are on the sheet, so looping would need a [`shape.type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shape.type), i believe.

Comment: The reason for the specific range is there are a couple of titleblock images that are at the top of the page the would need to remain the same.... although i could add code to bring those back into the proper dimensions as they are always on the page and thus can have a static name.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is what i settled on.

```
Private Sub Resize_Graph_Click()

'resize all shapes
Dim s As Shape
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet

For Each s In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    s.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
    s.Width = 491.72
    s.Height = 106.56

Next s

'set header shapes and button back to original size
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Company Label")).Select
    Selection.ShapeRange.Height = 43.92
    Selection.ShapeRange.Width = 131.76
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Product Label")).Select
    Selection.ShapeRange.Height = 49.68
    Selection.ShapeRange.Width = 134.64
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Resize_Graph")).Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Resize_Graph").Height = 38.16
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Resize_Graph").Width = 105.12
'keep button from moving after changing shape back and forth
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Resize_Graph")).Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Resize_Graph").Left = 380
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Resize_Graph").Top = 5

ActiveWorkbook.Close Savechanges:=True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You still need to work out when to resize the picture, but the example code below shows how you can specifically access a picture where the Top-Left corner of the picture is located within a given cell.

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestMe()
    Dim thePicture As Shape
    Set thePicture = GetPictureAt(Range("A45"))
    If Not thePicture Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "found it! (" & thePicture.Name & ")"
        With thePicture
            .Height = 75
            .Width = 75
            Debug.Print "resized to h=" & .Height & ", w=" & .Width
        End With
    Else
        Debug.Print "couldn't find the picture!"
    End If

End Sub

Private Function GetPictureAt(ByRef thisCell As Range) As Shape
    Dim thisCellTop As Long
    Dim thisCellBottom As Long
    Dim thisCellLeft As Long
    Dim thisCellRight As Long
    With thisCell
        thisCellTop = .Top
        thisCellLeft = .Left
        thisCellBottom = thisCellTop + .Height
        thisCellRight = thisCellLeft + .Width
    End With

    Dim shp As Variant
    With Sheet1
        For Each shp In .Shapes
            If shp.Type = msoPicture Then
                If (shp.Top >= thisCellTop) And (shp.Top <= thisCellBottom) Then
                    If (shp.Left >= thisCellLeft) And (shp.Left <= thisCellRight) Then
                        Set GetPictureAt = shp
                        Exit Function
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next shp
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Wow, that is some awesome work. Using what you guys gave me i put together a little code that works for me.  Thank you very much.